# Multiple sub queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Is it possible to get the result as below from the same table date-wise records:

```
               Enrolled   Enrolled as Email  Enrolled as Text Deals Redeemed   
<First Date>   7          5                  2                6
<Next Date>    9          3                  6               14
```

Table structure look something like this:

```
Customer_id, field1, field2, responsecode, created_date
```

My current query is something like this:

```
Select 
   Created,
   Enroll = (Select COUNT(*) from tblCustomer where field1 <> '' group by created),
   Email = (Select COUNT(field1) from tblCustomer where field1 = 'E-mail' and field1     <>    '' group by created),
   Cell = (Select COUNT(*) from tblCustomer where field1 = 'Cell Phone' and field1 <> ''    group by created)
from tblCustomer 
group by created 
order by created
```

Comment: what is your database/table structure?

Comment: What does the table look like? How is anyone supposed to answer this without the relevant information?

Comment: please elaborate. do you mean the records which contain dates? or something else?

Comment: Common field are as below: Customer_id,email,text,responsecode,created_date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select created_date,
       count(field1) Enrolled,
       count(case field1 when 'E-mail' then 1 end) Enrolled_as_Email,
       count(case field1 when 'Cell Phone' then 1 end) Enrolled_as_Cell,
       (Select COUNT(*)
        from tbl_TransactionDishout d
        where d.created = c.created_date and
              d.DishoutResponseCode = '0000') Deals_Redeemed
from tblCustomer c
group by created_date
order by created_date
```

Comment: @VishalSuthar: How about now?

Comment: Please check my question..I have updated it by adding my current query which is not working.

Comment: @VishalSuthar: Your table structure does not match the code in the queries - there is no `field1` in your table structure. Please can you correct your question?

Comment: I have modified @Mark Bannister

Comment: @VishalSuthar: I have again updated my answer - if this still does not answer your question then you must include more information: in what way does the amended query fail to meet your requirements? How is Enrolled as Text recorded on the table? How are Deals Redeemed stored on the table? Why are you storing customers with NULLs in field1? What is the purpose of field2? Are there any other relevant fields that have not been mentioned?

Comment: Your query works fine till now but one column is wrong, for more information for that I added this:

For Deals_Redeemed,I need another subquery 
Table name is "tbl_TransactionDishout"

        [Trnx_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [OfferNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [MerchantID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [TerminalID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [DishoutResponseCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [Created] [datetime] NULL

So the existing query for that is as below:

Select COUNT(*) from tbl_TransactionDishout where DishoutResponseCode = '0000'

So can you add this in your existing query.?

Comment: Displays as this:

2010-05-20 00:00:00.000 1 1 0 133
2010-05-22 00:00:00.000 2 2 0 133
2010-05-25 00:00:00.000 5 4 1 133
2010-05-27 00:00:00.000 1 1 0 133


Which means same count in all rows

Comment: @VishalSuthar: Updated accordingly - try now.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want a COUNT(), but instead, a SUM( CASE/WHEN )

```
Select 
      Created, 
      count(*) TotalCnt,
      SUM( CASE WHEN Field1 = 'E-mail' then 1 else 0 END ) as EMailCnt,
      SUM( CASE WHEN Field1 = 'Cell Phone' then 1 else 0 END ) as CellCnt,
      SUM( CASE WHEN RedeamedCondition then 1 else 0 END ) as RedeamCnt
   from 
      tblCustomer  
   group by 
      created  
   order by 
      created
```

Note... if created is a date/time you will need to have  the group by based on the date portion ONLY of the "created", otherwise you would get different counts for every second...  From another post, the following gets only the date portion of a date time by basically removing the hours:minutes:seconds portion

```
DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, created))
```

or if that doesn't make sense, you could just do it by

```
datepart( yy, created) as GrpYear,
datepart( mm, created) as GrpMonth,
datepart( dd, created) as GrpDay,  ... rest of columns.....
```